# Easiest/most efficient way to constantly check & read PHP file for database changes in Java?

Tags: java, php, mysql

I have a simple Friend System in PHP using a MySQL Database. I also have a Java application where a user can send a friend request to someone via the PHP system, and the recipient can accept it. When the user sends a friend request, the PHP writes the sender and the recipient's username into a table on the database, and right now in order to check for the friend request, the recipient has to manually refresh a PHP file (which outputs the sender's username).

I'm using HttpConnection to manually check the PHP file and load the output, but I am wondering if there is a way to constantly poll or keep an active connection that reads updated information from the PHP file so that the recipient can automatically be notified as soon as the sender sends a friend request instead of reloading the file every second (that doesn't use a whole lot of bandwidth).

Thanks.

Comment: These may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986529/long-polling-with-java-and-jboss http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824604/online-tutorials-for-implementing-comets-server-push

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX to keep checking instead of the user performing a hard refresh.

Other option would be using a webworker:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_web_workers

tkx