# Push APIs like gmail, twitter and facebook does

Tags: java, push

I want to create an application using pushing mechanism. i.e. without user interaction we can push the messages to the client when some thing is happend in the server, similar to what gmail is done for their emails and facebook recent activity messages.

How can i implement this one using java.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One technique to achive this is taking advantage of the long-polling method.

The client opens up a connection to the server, but instead of instantly returning the result, the server holds the connection for a period of time and delays his response.

If something happens, that causes the server response to trigger (new mail, new instant message ... ), the server finally answers to the client. Or, in the case the request runs in timeout, the server just passes an empty result.

In both cases, the client processes the response and instantly makes a new request, for the whole thing to start again.

In Java, the client side may do simple requests. The server side should be properly threaded, and the timout should not be set too long.

Also, please have a look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986529/long-polling-with-java-and-jboss):

> Each webserver/appserver has a pool of threads, say 10 threads for processing web requests, if all those threads will go into 'sleep' no other web request will be serviced until one of those 'sleeps' exists.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called as Comet aka Reverse Ajax, there are multiple such implementation both paid and free.

Depending upon programming language you choose you can choose one of the following:

1. Tomcat Reverse Ajax.
2. Jetty Comet.
3. DWR
4. Streamhub (Paid but has a community edition)
5. APE. (Free not available for Windows)
6. Atmosphere (Used in Primefaces)
7. CometD by Dojo.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) API. You use their REST service to publish events and Pusher then delivers these events to all clients via websockets. The API is easy to use and supports multiple channels.

Answer (score 0):

Though a late answer , here is my take on how to do server push.You can use the socket-io framework coupled with nodejs.The socket-io client has to listen to events and the socket-io on the nodejs ( server )  can emit ( push ) the messages , the client ( socket-io in webpage ) picks it up and can do whatever it wants.There is a catch,you should know a little bit of javascript.The socket-io protocol is transport agnostic too !

Here are the links

[An excellent writeup on using socket-io and nodejs](http://lynx.io/article/socketio-introduction)

[Socket-io](http://socket.io/)

[nodejs](http://nodejs.org/)